# Unusual Seal reading (Characters identified: 胸有方心身無媚骨)

Tags: character-identification, seal

Can someone help me to read this seal?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your character identification is correct. The sentence can be translated as “With a right consciousness, without any sycophancy.”